# Which crypto currency exchanges are using segwit (bc1) addresses for its users?

Tags: bech32-address, segregated-witness

Are any of the cryptocurrency exchanges using native segwit (bc1) addresses for any of its users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of November 2017, only Electrum wallet and blockchain.info are major services which support bech32 address format. A number of services use P2SH wrapped segwit scripts which is easier for backwards compatibility for the moment. This is expected due to the bech32 BIP ([BIP 173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki)) not being formalised at this point in time.

Comment: So do you recommend not to use bech32 addresses at the moment as they are not backwards compatible?

Comment: I'd suggest that services show the bech32 encoding first, and a legacy P2SH encapsulated version for those that don't support it yet. It's the only way that adoption will happen, otherwise you end up with a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: How does a legacy P2SH encapsulated version look?

Comment: It's indistinguishable from any other P2SH address until spending.